# Put php value in the end of a link

Tags: php

Script 1.

```html
add_action('asgarosforum_after_post_author', 'my_function_asgaros_cabinet', 10, 1);
function my_function_asgaros_cabinet($author_id) {
  $userData = get_userdata($author_id);

  if (!empty($userData) && !empty($userData->description)) {
    echo $userData->description; 
  }
}
```

Script 2.
I want to put this in script 1 and put ''description'' in the end of that link.
How to do that and whats the right way/code? Cause i think my code is wrong.

```html
<iframe src="http://test.com/me.php?sid='echo $userData->description'"></iframe>
```

Comment: `sid='echo $userData` that won't work. Why is there an echo in there without php tags?

Comment: @mickmackusa I love it when they also ignore comments, funny.... we/I didn't set our buttons to ignore.

Comment: @mickmackusa as it was. [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this. Feel free to upvote if you agree and haven't yet ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with adding the php tag:

```
<iframe src="http://test.com/me.php?sid=<?php echo $userData->description?>"></iframe>
```

or

You can try to write the all iframe tag with php:

```
echo '<iframe src="http://test.com/me.php?sid='. $userData->description .'"></iframe>'
```